# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade : stuck at xubuntu logo, no login screen and broken dpkg

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, dpkg

I was trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. For some reason the upgrade process wasn't successful and everything was frozen, so I restarted my system by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScr</kbd>+<kbd>REISUB</kbd>. Now my system is stuck at the Xubuntu logo.

I tried to boot into recovery mode and have a feeling that `dpkg` isn't configured properly. I followed the below steps to remount the filesystem to be able to update the files using:

```
mount -o remount , rw /
dpkg --configure -a`
```

but this led to an error, and I had to cancel it.

[image]

[image: systemctl error]

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked:

1. Recovery mode shell is not really required as only the GUI part was broken. Press Ctrl+Alt+F3 to login to a shell.
2. Run the following command to get rid of broken dpkg multiple times until it executes successfully.

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```